# Replace characters from string stored in database by using NSPredicate

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have phone numbers stored in database in the format like +1-541-634-4210 or +1 (541) 634-4210.

I want to search unformatted number like +15416344210 in the database by using NSPredicate but i unable to form the correct predicate format.

I try something like this

```
NSString *regex = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+0123456789"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number MATCHES %@ == %@",regex,phoneNumber]];
```

So any ideas on how to achieve that?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: show what you tried, explain what it does wrong, show some examples of what you mean

Comment: Why do you have that many format? It could be wiser to always save in the same format (moving your issue when saving the data).

Comment: @Wain Updated the predicate format

Comment: @Larme because this is as per my requirement. The numbers coming from server and i have to display number in the same format.

Comment: But you still could save 2 strings: the format given by the server, and apply "universal" format to save too, which would facilitate fetching.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using predicate.

**Swift**

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "[+][0-9]+")
predicate.evaluateWithObject(phone number)
```

**Objective-C**

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", "[+][0-9]+"];
[predicate evaluateWithObject:phoneNumber];
```

Please update the right string based on your conditions.

Comment: how this work with the core data with NSFetchRequest?

Comment: @shubham I think you ask about retrieve data from database with core data

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"number MATCHES %@", [[filter componentsSeparatedByString:@"- "] objectAtIndex:0]];
```